Grouping toast notifications with collections
I want to group toast notification by Collection on Windows.
There's an example at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-collections, but I get an exception when running it.
public async void CreateToastCollection()
{
    string str = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string folderPath = @$"{str}" + "\\warning.png"; // /Red.jpg

    string displayName = "Work Email";
    string launchArg = "NavigateToWorkEmailInbox";
    Uri icon = new Uri(folderPath); //"ms-appx:///Assets/workEmail.png"

    // Constructor
    ToastCollection workEmailToastCollection = new ToastCollection(
        "MyToastCollection",
        displayName,
         launchArg,
        icon);

    // Calls the platform to create the collection
    await ToastNotificationManager.GetDefault().GetToastCollectionManager().SaveToastCollectionAsync(workEmailToastCollection);
}
public async void Toast() 
{
    // Construct the content
    var content = new ToastContentBuilder()
        .AddText("Adam sent a message to the group")
        .GetToastContent();

    // Create the toast
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());

    // Get the collection notifier
    var notifier = await ToastNotificationManager.GetDefault().GetToastNotifierForToastCollectionIdAsync("MyToastCollection") ?? null;

    // And show the toast
    notifier.Show(toast);
}


exception : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been > thrown by the target of an invocation.'

I think the issue is ToastCollection wasn't created so it's null. Because of that, Show() can't find the correct collection. I don't know how to fix it.
I've tried all the methods for ToastCollection, but I need it to work like Microsoft's example in my Windows notification center.
